# GPS Tracking device data intepretation

Tags: php, gps, gis

I have developed a GPS server using PHP. I am able to get the data from a Redview device that comes up as per the below string.

```
$$10737020005???&A9955&B085439.000,A,0116.8607,S,03645.5800,E,0.00,271.45,270911,,,A*7B|1.1|&C0000011111&D00269<21&E00000001&Y00000000##
```

I have managed to split the string into separate portions and successfully stored the data in a MySql database table.

Question:

What does the following string mean?

```
A*7B|1.1|&C0000011111&D00269<21&E00000001&Y00000000##
```

Comment: I have tested another device but instead of giving out a unit ID as per what I configured it, it gives in a totally different format as follows: $$ h?sp  _ ÖU163240.298,A,0118.3741,S,03645.3077,E,001.
5,010.2,011011,,, where $$ h?sp  _ ÖU should be indicating the unit ID. The unit ID I configured was 10737020005. How can i interpret such data.

Answer (score 4):

*7B = Checksum, but the rest of it is probably proprietary data that Redview tacked on to the end.  Usually, companies keep this data private (though a lot has been reverse engineered for several manufacturers) and sell it to developers.

Check out Wikipedia's entry on [NMEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183) for further links and info.

Comment: I have tested another device but instead of giving out a unit ID as per what I configured it, it gives in a totally different format as follows: $$ h?sp _ ÖU163240.298,A,0118.3741,S,03645.3077,E,001. 5,010.2,011011,,, where $$ h?sp _ ÖU should be indicating the unit ID. The unit ID I configured was 10737020005. How can i interpret such data.

Comment: What is the hex code for `$$ h?sp _ ÖU`?  When that hex is converted to decimal, is it anywhere close to 10737020005?

Comment: Decimal to Hex for 10737020005 is 27FF9EC65, I guess $$ h?sp _ ÖU? is not Hex since hex has 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F and that none of this characters can be seen. I have tested configuring different devices of the same type but all send ID in that format e.g. $$ f?sp  _ ÖU and $$ V?tIô2  ÖU which is a bit crazy

Comment: The `$$ ` and `ÖU` are quite possibly separators or just data that is the same between devices.  If the values between them are consistent, then they could likely be the identifiers you are looking for, just somehow encoded.

Comment: Sure. I agree with you on the separators. The data between the separators is somehow consistent per device. Decoding is the key problem since I fail to understand the format. It is not Hex as per my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

These strings are very similar to Meilago, Bofan, Access Tech etc. messages, which I have seen before. Checking the Redview site I think they sell quite the same device that I used before; as far as I know basically the same devices are sold with several different brand names. I suggest asking Redview for the protocol docs, or checking other suppliers: I found one [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/92340065/Meiligao-GPRS-Communication-Protocol-GT30i-GT60-VT300-VT310-VT400-V2-1), but there are several other specs [out there](http://www.google.hu/search?q=gprs%20gprs%20protocol%20documentation%20pdf). Actually I just found a [redview](http://ebookbrowse.com/redview-gtp-gprs-communication-protocol-for-gps-tracker-v3-0-pdf-d71217382) specs too.

It's hard to tell which command (client device message type) your string covers, as the corresponding 2 bytes would be ??, and there is nothing defined for 3F3F (supposing ASCII encoding). The substring quoted above is the specific data of the given command. You may check the server side maybe if there is everything OK with receiving and logging the messages: I suggest reading integers (bytes) from the socket, and log them carefully (eg. encoding).